# How do you translate « the former »?

Tags: traduction

Je sais que la locution « ce dernier » veut dire « the latter » mais je n’ai pourtant jamais vu « ce premier ». Est-ce bien juste? Par exemple,

> Elle précise que l’aide fournie doit avoir pour but de faire que les pays aidés n’aient plus besoin de ces premiers.

Merci d’avance!

Comment: les premiers et les derniers: the former and the latter.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary before you asked the question? Even online dictionaries have it. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/the-former

Comment: @None, Yes I was asking if using the word ce is appropriate. In wordreference for example, under latter there is an explicit entry for « ce dernier » whereas former doesn’t have the word ce. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: French often uses *ce* dernier, but in the English translation, we would not say "this latter" in most cases.

Comment: Clearly my question isn’t very clear, sorry about that; but basically, ce is used with dernier to mean "the latter", is ce used with premier to mean the former? From all examples I can find online it has to be paired with a noun after « ce premier film », etc. Never by itself to mean former. (Another way to phrase my question: online dictionaries say « le dernier » and « ce dernier » mean latter, they also say « le premier » means former, but I haven’t found one that says « ce premier » means former)

Comment: @User I voted to close this question mostly because of the title. The way it was asked made it seem like it was about the connector *the former*, which had already been covered on this site. I realize now, reading your comment, that your question is valid. You should probably either edit this question or ask another one with the format: "Pourquoi *ce premier* est utilisé dans cette phrase même si *ce premier* est considéré comme incorrect".